# Entity framework Code-First - backup and restore DbContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

I trying to backup data on Model change and recreate it after database creation.
It's work fine but I need to write this for each class.
How can I get all DbSet in DbContext and loop with this functions on it?

**backup:**

```
XmlSerializer classSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<TextComponent>));
StreamWriter classComponentWriter = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/backup/TextComponents.xml"));
classSerializer.Serialize(classComponentWriter, _db.TextComponents.ToList());
classComponentWriter.Close();
```

**restore:**

```
List<TextComponent> TextComponents = null;
XmlSerializer TextComponentSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<TextComponent>));
FileStream TextComponentFileStream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/backup//TextComponents.xml"), FileMode.Open);
TextComponents = (List<TextComponent>)TextComponentSerializer.Deserialize(TextComponentFileStream);

foreach (TextComponent item in TextComponents)
{
_db.TextComponents.Add(item);
}
_db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection to enumerate all DBSet properties:

```
properties = typeof(DBContext).GetProperties(); // or this.GetType().GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)  
{  
    if (/*Check if property type is DBSet by comparing [property.DeclaringType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.declaringtype.aspx)*/)  
        // Write backup or restore code here.  
}
```

`